# Enable some component visibility in MATLAB GUI figure after a selection?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a simple question about matlab GUI? 
how can i Enable some component visibility in MATLAB GUI figure? For an easy understanding i am using a fgure to explain my problem.

I wanted to do something like.
After Running my Gui. i wanted to show only a specific pushbutton rather all the components
as shown in Figure 1 
[image: Figure 1]

Once i click on **Lets ADD** Button the figure 2 should appear
[image: figure 2]

After selecting a number my Other Components should appear as shown in figure 3.

[image]

Sorry if my Words are misleading to you as i do not have a good command on technical words.

Thanks..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the event (i.e. press button) and create a function for that.
There you will need to enable the visibility of whatever you want like:

```
set(handles.pushbutton1,'visible','on')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . i will check it. Could you please post some Example Output Images..... otherwise its ok.........

Comment: Example images? They should be Exactly the same that you posted. Try it ;)